# Create a metric that shows the number of issues of an specific rule in SonarQube 5.6

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I am developing a plugin for SonarQube 5.6.6 using the Java Plugin API. I've created some custom rules (checks) and, now, I want to create **a custom metric that shows how many issues of certain rules a project has**, for example, the number of issues of rule `MyCustomRule`.

I know SonarQube users can go to page *Issues* and filter with the names of those certain rules, so they can see how many issues exist, but I want the number on page *Measures*.

I have a class implementing `MeasureComputer`:

```
public class MyMeasureComputer implements MeasureComputer {

    @Override
    public MeasureComputerDefinition define(MeasureComputerDefinitionContext defContext) {
        return defContext.newDefinitionBuilder()
                .setOutputMetrics(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void compute(MeasureComputerContext context) {
        int totalSum = 0;
        for (Measure measure : context.getChildrenMeasures(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key())) {
            totalSum += measure.getIntValue();
        }

        context.addMeasure(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key(), totalSum);
    }
}
```

This class defines an output metric, which is the number of issues I said before. In method `compute`, it gets the values of measures `MY_CUSTOM_METRIC` of each file and sum them all. Finally, it creates the measure `MY_CUSTOM_METRIC`, which is the number of issues.

At this point, I need to define the value of the measure `MY_CUSTOM_METRIC` in each file, so `MyMeasureComputer` can compute it, but I don't know how to do it. I think it should be in a `Sensor`:

```
public class MySensor implements Sensor {

    @Override
    public void describe(SensorDescriptor descriptor) {
        descriptor.name("MySensor").onlyOnLanguage(Java.KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(SensorContext context) {
        final FileSystem fs = context.fileSystem();

        for (InputFile file : fs.inputFiles(fs.predicates().all())) {
            context.<Integer>newMeasure()
                .forMetric(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC)
                .on(file)
                .withValue(getNumCertainIssues(context, file))
                .save();
        }
    }

    private int getNumCertainIssues(SensorContext context, InputFile file) {
        return 10;   // TODO: how to get the number of issues?
    }

}
```

In method `execute`, I can set a metric in each file with an example value (10) and it works; I can see it in SonarQube UI (page "Measures") along with the sum of every 10:

[image: Total]

[image: Every file]

My questions are:

- how do I get the number of issues of an specific rule?
- should it be done in class `Sensor`?
- is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MeasureComputer is executed on each components : files, directories, modules and project.

- On files (`Component#getType#FILE`), you're then able to get issues (using `MeasureComputerContext#getIssues`), count the number of issues from rule `MyCustomRule`, then save it using `MeasureComputerContext#addMeasure`.
- On none file components you compute the measure from children and save it, which is the code you have written.

You code will look something like that :

```
public class MyMeasureComputer implements MeasureComputer {
    @Override
    public MeasureComputerDefinition define(MeasureComputerDefinitionContext defContext) {
        return defContext.newDefinitionBuilder()
                .setOutputMetrics(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key())
                .build();
    }
```

`@Override
   public void compute(MeasureComputerContext context) {
        if (context.getComponent().getType() == FILE) {
           List<Issue> fileIssues = context.getIssues();
           // TODO get number of issues of type MyCustomRule
           context.addMeasure(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key(), sum);
        return;
    } 
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (Measure measure : context.getChildrenMeasures(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key())) {
        totalSum += measure.getIntValue();
    }

    context.addMeasure(MY_CUSTOM_METRIC.key(), totalSum);
}`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I could achieve my goal! To complete your answer I have to say that the code I wrote in class `MySensor` shouldn't exist (moreover, I deleted the whole class), since you would get an error because of defining a metric twice for a file.

Comment: Good news ! And indeed, I forgot to say the no sensor should be created.